# Mongodb Aggregation Map reduce

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I have started exploring mongodb couple of weeks back. I have a scenario here. I have a collection which has 3 million records.

I would want to perform aggregation on the aggreation based on two keys (also need to use match condition). I used aggregation framework for the same. I came to know that aggregation would fail if the processing document size (array) exceeds 16 MB.

I faced the same issue when i tried. I am trying to use map reduce now. I would need the guidance on implementing the same. How can I overcome the 16 MB size limit by using map reduce?

Also I came to know that I can do it by splitting the collection into multiple collections and do the aggregation on the same. Would be great if anyone can point me in right direction?

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data and what query you are executing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even without code there are basic answers to your questions.

The limitation on the [BSON document 16MB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#BSON-Document-Size) output size is for "inline" responses. That means a response from your operations that does not write the individual "documents" from your response to a collection.

So with [**`mapReduce`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/) a statement much like this:

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
    mapper,
    reducer,
    { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
)
```

Has the problem that the "array" in the response needs to be under 16MB. But if you change this to output to a collection:

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
    mapper,
    reducer,
    { "out": { "replace": "newcollection" } }
)
```

Then you no longer have this limitation.

The same applies to the [aggregate](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method from versions 2.6 and upwards using the [**`$out`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) pipeline stage:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
   // lots of pipeline

   { "$out": "newcollection }

])
```

This overcomes the limtation by the same means by outputing to a collection.

Actually with the aggregate statement, again from version 2.6 and upwards this returns a [cursor](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.6/#aggregation-enhancements), just like the [**`.find()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) method, and is also not subject to this limitation.